# Start Command in CMD Window

Tags: windows, cmd

I use below command in CMD window:

```
start notepad.exe
```

Is `start` a short-cut for an executable in Windows like:

```
C:\Windows\System32\start.exe
```

or is it a parameter to be passed to `cmd.exe`?

When I use

```
wcsript test.vbs
```

`wcsript` refers to

```
C:\Windows\System32\wcsript .exe
```

So I want to ask does same apply for `start` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some commands available in CMD are built directly into CMD.EXE.  I believe start, like dir, is one of those commands.  You won't find a separate program called dir.exe or start.exe.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use start, simply the location of your script with the filename+extension works.

The reason you can start notepad is because it is inside the Windows folder where CMD also is.

If it's on your desktop use: C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\test.vbs
If you have multiple files you can make a script using:

> cd C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\
>
> test1.vbs
>
> test2.vbs